# Rails -- Single Table Inheritance -- conceptual question about model relationships

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, single-table-inheritance

I wanted to know if it is possible to have STI where the subclasses each relate to an unrelated model in different ways.

In other words, say `B < A` and `C < A`, and I implement single table inheritance on table `A` (e.g. a type column where you can have `B` or `C` to indicate a subclass).

Now let's say we have a separate model called `Xyzzy`.

Is it possible to implement a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between `C` and `Xyzzy` while implementing a `has_one` relationship between `B` and `Xyzzy`?

How should I do this in the context of STI?  Or would STI simply not affect this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing particular to do to make this happen. Simply create your relationships.

Indeed, even if `B` and `C` have access to some columns they don't care about, well... they simply don't care about.